# Maven profile dependency with another profile

Tags: maven, maven-2

When I do `mvn clean install` it will run a default active maven profile and the Master POM.

When I do `mvn clean install -P anotherProfile` it is executing default active maven profile + anotherProfile.

But if default profile fails i don't want the another profile to run.how do i do it?

eg:

```
mvn clean install - default active profile
mvn clean install -P anotherProfile - default+anotherProfile
```

the second line works fine but I don't want it to run `anotherprofile` if default profile fails.

Comment: Are you on Windows/Linux/Mac OS X ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/40064/wim-deblauwe : windows

Answer (score -2):

If you want one profile to be activated but another one to be disabled you can use a ! to disable it:

```
mvn install -P profile1
```

will activate profile1

```
mvn install -P profile2,!profile1
```

will activate profile2 but de-activate profile1

You may be able to use the activation of the profiles to turn them on or off depending on some properties and to not rely on manual activation.

see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html